# Que significa este error en Flask? CompileError: Don't know how to render literal SQL value: None

Tags: python, sql, flask

Estoy realizando una serie de ejercicios en Flask pertenecientes a un curso en el que hay que desarrollar un programa de compra y venta de acciones de bolsa. El caso es que al probar el programa a traves del navegador funciona bien, si  embargo con la herramienta de testeo del curso, el cual supongo que introduce datos por la linea de comandos, me salta el siguiente error:

CompileError: Don't know how to render literal SQL value: None

Alguien me puede explicar que significa este error. He buscado en distintas fuentes pero no lo tengo claro del todo.
El error salta al llegar a la siguiente función:

```
@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    """Buy shares of stock"""
    if request.method == "POST":

        stockToBuy = request.form.get("symbol")

        # Check that input field for stock is not empty
        if not stockToBuy:
            return apology("Stock's symbol field is empty", 400)

        # Check that stock's symbol exists in API (use lookup function from helpers.py)
        quote = lookup(stockToBuy)

        if quote is None:
            return apology("Stock symbol doesn't exists", 400)

        # Check that number of shares is not empty and it's positive integer
        try:
            shares = int(request.form.get("shares"))
        except:
            return apology("Invalid input. Number of shares must be a positive integer", 400)

        if shares < 0:
            return apology("Number of shares must be a positive number", 400)

        # Look up stock's current price
        currentPrice = quote["price"]

        # Get logged user's id
        user_id = request.form.get("user_id")

        # Look for user's current cash in database
        try:
            rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", user_id)
        except:
            rows = 0

        if rows == 1:
            userCash = rows[0]["cash"]

            # Calculate total price of stocks about to buy and substract it from user's current cash
            totalPrice = currentPrice * shares
            totalCash = userCash - totalPrice

            # Check if user can afford the number of shares at current price
            if totalPrice > userCash:
                return apology("Not enough cash to afford this operation!", 400)

            # If user can afford the opeartion. Insert transaction data into transactions table
            db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, symbol, name, qty, transaction_type, price, date, total) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, 'bought', ?, DATETIME('now'), ?)", user_id, stockToBuy, quote["name"], shares, currentPrice, totalPrice)

            # Update user's available cash
            db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = ? WHERE id = ?", totalCash, user_id)

        # UPDATE QUANTITY IN 'stocks_owned' table
        # Retrieve data from stocks_owned to check if current stock exists
        current_qtyStock = db.execute("SELECT qty FROM stocks_owned WHERE user_id = ? AND symbol = ?", user_id, stockToBuy)

        # If symbol and name doesn't exists yet
        if not current_qtyStock:
            db.execute("INSERT INTO stocks_owned (user_id, symbol, name, qty) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", user_id, stockToBuy, quote["name"], shares)

        else:
            current_qtyStock[0]['qty'] += shares
            db.execute("UPDATE stocks_owned SET qty = ? WHERE user_id = ? AND symbol = ?", current_qtyStock, user_id, stockToBuy)

        return redirect("/")

    else:
        return render_template("buy.html")
```

De más está decir que soy bastante nuevo en el uso Python y Flask!!!
Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Mi sospecha es que tras la linea `user_id = request.form.get("user_id")` la variable `user_id` se queda con el valor `None`. Puedes comprobarlo haciendo un `print(user_id)` tras esa línea. Si esto es así, es que no estás recibiendo un campo llamado `"user_id"` en el form de entrada. Revisa que el campo se llama realmente así, y que la herramienta de testeo te lo envía en un FORM HTML (y no por ejemplo en un json)

Comment: O tal vez es un test que tu aplicación no pasa, consistente en ver si "rompe" cuando no recibe un campo "user_id". ¿Tienes una especificación que te diga qué habrías de hacer si no se le envía un "user_id"? ¿Tal vez retornar un error 400 y una apology de esas que retornas para otros casos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@abulafia eres un crack!!! Tu sospecha era cierta. No me estaba retornando el campo user_id. He cambiado esa linea por esta: user_id = session['user_id'] y ahora si funciona... aunque me saltan otros errores pero esos sí que se de donde vienen.